# Convert low voltage accelerometer to Wake ATTiny Open Source Binary Watch, activate on wrist motion

Tags: microcontroller, avr, low-power, accelerometer, binary

I'm working on building a binary watch similar to njeer's binary watch featured on hackaday

I am planning on using a cr2032 3.0V 190mAh battery. So in order for this to run for any length of time I'll need to keep the ATTiny in sleep mode until the user actives the watch. I found [this](https://bigdanzblog.wordpress.com/2014/08/10/attiny85-wake-from-sleep-on-pin-state-change-code-example/) to be a good resource for that.

What I'm wondering is how I can convert the voltage output of a [AD22279-A-R2](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Analog-Devices/AD22279-A-R2/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvwE4h8i4g3cmpdANGD53Y6boChDT1oB%252b8%3D) accelerometer to something that an ATTiny85 can wake up on. And make it only wake up give the right wrist flick or motion.

Comment: It's probably better not to use an analog accelerometer, but rather to use a digitally interfaced one with a programmable wake alarm / interrupt output.

Comment: I totally agree with Chris. Have a look at the [ADXL350](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL350.pdf). 3-Axis, i²c, spi and automatic detection of events like activity, tap, double tap and free fall (signaled via digital output pins). In addition, it consumes 40nA, which is 30 times less then the AD22279-A-R2's 1.3mA.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks, I have found the [MMA8451Q](http://cache.nxp.com/files/sensors/doc/data_sheet/MMA8451Q.pdf)

this particular chip has an orientation based interupt which looks to be what I'll need.

Comment: I will add website details when this comes closer to becoming a reality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ATTiny85 includes an analog comparator that can wake the processor and generate an interrupt when the voltage on the AIN0 pin exceeds or falls below the voltage on the AIN1 pin.

Comment: That's very useful, I was not aware of this.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it looks like all of data on mouser's catalog concerning these device's power usage is very inaccurate. The lowest power analog accelerometer I could find is the [ADXL325](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/609/ADXL325-245983.pdf_) with typical supply current of 350uA